# Docker swarm cannot find image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-registry

I deploy a docker swarm with 6 nodes. I built some images and I am trying to add them as services to the swarm. I have 5 microservices. When I run the on one host with docker-compose everything works fine. I run this command docker service create rate --with-registry-auth and I get the following message.

```
image rate:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access rate:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.

yyf9m49xw3enwano1scr55ufc
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: No such image: rate:latest
```

I run docker images and the rate image is appeared. rate is the repository name. I also tried with the image id but didn't worked. The only images that I can add to swarm is images that is public.

Comment: Without seeing a [mcve] it's a little tricky to say more; can you [edit] the question to include enough source code to demonstrate the issue, or is this not a programming question?  My experience is a little more in Kubernetes than Swarm, but there I can tell you that it's basically required to push your images into a registry before trying to run them in via a cluster orchestrator.

Answer (score 2):

```
image rate:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access rate:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

This error indicates you are trying to run an image that was never pushed to a registry. Push your images to a registry first. And then you can run them on any node in the cluster (which will pull any missing images from that registry). If the registry requires authentication to pull the image, then run `docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth ...`, but you must first push the image, and specific the pushed image name (which will not be `rate:latest` since you do not have access to push to the official library on Docker Hub).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35187) on the Moby project about that.

If you tried already to set --with-registry-auth but didn't solved it, you should manually login to each cluster worker node and pull the Docker images.